# Garden Variety Family

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, knowledge

Some siblings* were discussing the unique mathematical qualities of their respective ages the other day, and they determined that at one point in history, the following equations were true.

$\hskip 2.7 in a = b * c$
$\hskip 2.7 in a = b * 2$
$\hskip 2.7 in c = b * 4$
$\hskip 2.7 in c - b = 0$
$\hskip 2.7 in d = e * f$
$\hskip 2.7 in d = e * 3$
$\hskip 2.7 in f = e * 7$
$\hskip 2.7 in g = f * 2$
$\hskip 2.7 in g = h * 1$
$\hskip 2.7 in g = e + f$

Numbers are "age in years" rounded to the nearest whole number age, and each letter variable is representative of an individual sibling's age.

---

Now, the question to you is:

### What is their mother's unfortunate nickname?

---

<sub>* *Human* siblings</sub>

Comment: @athin I recently saw [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ENY6I0B2yo) in which she talks about how she hates the nickname, and I genuinely feel bad that she (and her children) have been burdened by it.

Comment: Riddles should be clever and creative. Riddles that are too easy or unimaginative are not fun to solve, although it is hard to draw a line here since difficulty is very subjective. In addition, riddles with crucial details omitted can frustrate solvers.

Comment: A quote from Rand al'Thor from https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/list-examples-of-things-you-think-are-on-topic-or-off-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of these equations is true if

> They were all born at the same time since each equation holds true if $a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h$

That means that...

> The mother gave birth to octuplets (8 children at once).

And the mother's name is...

> Octomom, the mother of the second set of octuplets to be born alive in the US